# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or ...?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un trabajo escolar que justo es para consultar calificaciones lo estoy haciendo en php y ya tengo el login pero al momento de que doy clic sobre mi menu para que me muestre mis calificaciones me manda el siguiente error estoy usando **Xampp**  les dejo mi código  supongo que mi error esta en la consulta de cuando quiero mandar a llamar las calificaciones del usuario que inicio session  ojala me pudieran ayudar con mi consulta o como hago el recorrido si es que en alguna de las dos estoy mal.

Línea 58 de mi código es esta justo la de la consulta:

```
$calf=mysql_query("'SELECT * FROM boleta WHERE CURP = $_SESSION['Usuario']'");
```

Error que aparece en xampp:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in ...... on line 58

Código:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['Usuario'];
include "./conexion.php";
$re=mysql_query("select * from user_alumno where CURP='".$_POST['Usuario']."' AND 
          CONTRASENA='".$_POST['Password']."'") or die(mysql_error());
  while ($f=mysql_fetch_array($re)) {
      $arreglo[]=array('Id'=>$_POST['id']);

  }
  if(isset($arreglo)){
    $_SESSION['Usuario']=$arreglo;
    header("Location: ../admin.php");
  }else{
    header("Location: ../login.php?error=datos no validos");
  }

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<head>
<link href="csscali.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>REPORTES</title>
<link href="csscali" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/estilos.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  href="./js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <center><h1>CALIFICACIONES</h1></center>
   <?php mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
   mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); ?>


  <table border="0px" width="100%"> 
    <tr>
      <td>Curp</td>
      <td>Materia</td>
      <td>Calificacion 1</td>
      <td>Calificacion 2</td>
      <td>Calificacion 3</td>
      <td>Calificacion Final</td>
      <td>Asistencia 1</td>
      <td>Asistencia 2</td>
      <td>Asistencia 3</td>

    </tr> 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Usuario'])){
        $calf= $_POST['id'];
    $calf=mysql_query("'SELECT * FROM boleta WHERE CURP = $_SESSION['Usuario']'");
    $result = mysql_query($calf);
    if (mysql_num_rows($calf)>0) {
          $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
          $_SESSION["Usuario"] = $row['id'];
            $calf=$_POST['id'];
          echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$calf['CURP'].'</td>
            <td>'.$calf['MATERIA'].'</td>
            <td>'.$calf['CALIFICCION1'].'</td>
              <td>'.$calf['CALIFICCION2'].'</td>
              <td>'.$calf['CALIFICCION3'].'</td>
              <td>'.$calf['CALIFICCION_FINAL'].'</td>
              <td>'.$calf['ASISTENCIA1'].'</td>
              <td>'.$calf['ASISTENCIA2'].'</td>
              <td>'.$calf['ASISTENCIA3'].'</td>

          </tr>';
                }
                }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

tienes varias comillas que abren/cierran incorrectamente.

creo que con:

```
$calf=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boleta WHERE CURP = $_SESSION['Usuario']");
```

debería funcionarte. Observa que he quitado las comillas simple que tienes al inicio y fin del Select.
Por otra parte, dado que no indicas como es el codigo CURP de tu aplicación, he supuesto que es un entero, y por tanto va sin entrecomillar. Si fuera una cadena, te recomendaria cambiarlo por:

```
$curp = $_SESSION('Usuario');
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM boleta WHERE CURP = '%s'", $curp);
$calf=mysql_query($sql);
```

**NOTA**: Dado que utilizas directamente la variable $_SESSION, tu código puede ser objetivo de ataques de inyección SQL. Revisa la seguridad en tu código.

Comment: de echo es  de tipo  varchar, el curp lo estoy usando desde mi base de datos y es el que uso como usuario o id para el login es decir que es nombre de usuario=curp y es el que ocupo para identificar al usuario el cual esta realizando la consulta de sus calificaciones y ya corregi de echo la consulta  pero sigue sin imprimirme nada si quito el *where curp  * si me imprime las calificaciones de todos los usuarios en la base pero solo quiero del usuario que inicio session

Comment: <?php
$usuario = $_SESSION['Usuario'];
       $re=mysql_query("select * from boleta where CURP" =  '$usuario'  );
       $Curp=$_SESSION['Usuario'];

    while ($calf = mysql_fetch_array($re)) {
    if($Curp !=$calf['Curp']){
      
         } 
$re=$calf['Curp'];
          echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$calf['CURP'].'</td>;
           ......// asi quedo mi consulta pero aun sigue sin imprimirme los datos en la tabla aun que la tabla ya me la muestra aun que vacía.

Comment: En el codigo que te he puesto de solución, asigno la cadena de consulta en un $sql. haz despues un **echo $sql** para ver que te esta construyendo. Igual no se esta asignando bien la variable $curp o el valor de $_SESSION('Usuario') no esta bien guardado (o se pierde en algun otro proceso)

Answer (score 0):

Hola quita las comillas simples al inicio y al final y la variable de sesión agrégala a otra variable limpia para no tener que insertar el [] dentro del insert:

```
$usuario = $_SESSION['Usuario'];
$calf=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boleta WHERE CURP = '$usuario' ");
```

Comment: <?php
$usuario = $_SESSION['Usuario'];
       $re=mysql_query("select * from boleta where CURP" =  '$usuario'  );
       $Curp=$_SESSION['Usuario'];

    while ($calf = mysql_fetch_array($re)) {
    if($Curp !=$calf['Curp']){
      
         } 
$re=$calf['Curp'];
          echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$calf['CURP'].'</td>;
           ......// asi quedo mi consulta pero aun sigue sin imprimirme los datos en la tabla aun que la tabla ya me la muestra aun que vacía.

Comment: veo que tienes mal la consulta $re=mysql_query("select * from boleta where CURP" = '$usuario' ); tienes mal las comillas dobles " tu consulta  deberia ser: $re=mysql_query("select * from boleta where CURP = '$usuario'  ");